# Which one would be easier DC to DC or AC to DC

Tags: power-supply, variable

I have 440V 3 phase power that will be full wave rectified to 600V DC.  My question is, would I be better off plucking one of the phases and rectifying the 120V AC to 12V DC or one of the DC rectified legs and dropping that down to 12V DC?  The DC lines will vary from 20V to 200V.  The 12V will power a control board so the source needs to be clean.

I'm mechanical so my understanding of electrical is limited and the DC input variation is what has me wondering.

Update:
The only answer I received implied that you can not tap a single leg of a 3 phase power supply to get a singe phase 100-150V supply.  I thought this could be done?

So higher variable (20-200)DC voltage to 12V DC voltage or
157V AC to 12V DC? Would one be easier and cheaper than the other?

This is what I remember from school.  The 12V DC supply needs to no more than 3A.
[image]

My apologies here is the site.
https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/three-phase-power-measurement

Comment: If your understanding of electrical is limited, you should find a qualified person to work on Line voltages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The original question said 440 V, 3-phase. The edit suggests that you are discussing a 230 V, 3-phase supply. Please [edit] again to clarify and maybe state your country / location.

Comment: ircsmith - Hi, Currently your question breaks the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing) material copied/adapted from elsewhere. To comply with that rule, please [edit] the question & add the PDF / video / webpage name and its link, for the source of that copied image. Also please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future too. || As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums. TY

Answer (score 1):

No combination of 400 V, 3-phase + neutral connections will give you 120 V.

If you have a neutral connection then the phase-neutral voltage will be \$ V_{P-N} = \frac {440}{\sqrt 3} = 257\ \text V\$. Since this is outside the standard universal power supply range of 100 - 250 V AC, 50/60 Hz, that makes it unlikely that you will find a ready made PSU.

I recommend using a single-phase transformer with primary rated for phase-neutral or phase-phase voltage and secondary rated for a suitable AC-DC supply.

Comment: There are industrial cabinet-use PSUs that are rated for 200-500V, but they are expensive, but perhaps not as expensive as the parts and labor of putting together a step-down control transformer and a separate power supply. They are especially worth the price if the panel is full.